# Weird output from a LSTM NN

Tags: javascript, lstm, brain.js

I'm having a weird unexpected output out of a LSTM NN with brain.js that I want to understand

hello ,
I am new to NN and ML and I tried to play a little bit with the string-classification exemple of brain.js , as you can see in the code I added one more object to the training data and then changed a "little" bit the iterations count.
When I ran the program for the test value of "Code" I expected at least to get an output of one of the four letters of what I initially gave in my data set , but I got instead of that a weird output of "alla" !
Can somebody please tell me why is that so :C ? and please note that I am a new to ML and I just got overwhelmed by all the new concepts.

```
const brain = require('brain.js/dist/index').default;

const config = {
    iterations: 15000,
    log: true,
    logPeriod: 1,
    layers: [10]
  };

  // create data which will be used for training

  const data = [
/*
  10 training data of inputs starting by "a", "b" and "c"
  and their corresponding output
  none of them contains a sub string of "alla" in case you're wondering
*/ 
    { input: "Penguin", output: "p" },
];

  // the thing we would test
  const test = "Code";

  const network = new brain.recurrent.LSTM();
  network.train(data, config);
  const output = network.run(test);
  console.log(`It starts with: ${output}`); // It starts with: c
```

## output :

[image: https://i.imgur.com/hxBHtfg.png]

Answer (score -1):

You actually have only one item as training data; that is not enough for the network to learn from. I guess this could lead to weird output.